# Print head won’t clean, despite multiple cleaning processes

Tags: printing, printer, cleaning

I’ve got an Epson WF-7620 printer. I first started using the printer a little over two years ago. To date the printer has printed approximately 5000 pages. I have always used 3rd party ink cartridges with this printer, apart from the original Epson cartridges that came pre installed. 
The printer gets used pretty much every day, Monday - Friday.

Through out the printer’s life it has required lots of print head cleaning, probably twice a month. Cleaning often does not work first time and requires multiple cleans.

But recently no amount of cleaning seems to clean to print heads. 
I must have tried cleaning it 15 times, but the colours CMY
never pass the print head test sheet test. The black is fine.

Any ideas what I can do to get the print heads clean again?

Comment: maybe try using a vacuum cleaner to clean it ??

Comment: "no amount of cleaning seems to clean to print heads" - sometimes it just needs to be replaced.

Comment: tbh, that's why people buy laser printers. Unless you do a lot of high quality photos, inkjet aren't worth the effort. The less you use any head, the more likely it is to clog up, that will be why your black is OK.

Comment: 3rd party cartridges ? Did you remove the stickers covering up vent holes - mainly on 3rd party cartridges ?

Comment: @Emiley yes all stickers are removed, new cartridges have been installed as i thought it might be a cartridge error, but dont think it is.